# Joomla Contact Form - default_form.php file modification

Tags: checkbox, joomla, customization, contact-form

I am adding custom checkboxes and radio buttons to my Joomla website.

One of the requirements for replacing the browsers checkboxes and radio buttons, is the Input tags must be above the label tags. Why is a mystery to me, maybe someone can explain this also.

Anyhow, I have attempted to modify the Joomla \components\com_contact\views\contact\tmpl\default_form.php file by simply reversing the order for the send email copy checkbox.

[image: Before any changes]
When I review the modified contact page in a browser and inspect, the order has not changed ...... nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

The changes are like whats show below....

```
<dt><?php echo $this->form->getInput('contact_email_copy'); ?></dt>     
<dd><?php echo this->form->getLabel('contact_email_copy'); ?></dd>
```

Comment: are you doing this in template folder?

Comment: The file should be either in components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_form.php or templates/yourtemplate/html/com_contact/contact/default_form.php

Comment: I corrected the path to file...

Do you have any ideas as to why my modification isn't working?

Comment: see if the file reside in templates/yourtemplate/html/com_contact/contact/default_form.php, joomla prioritize this location first.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rahul. Went to my template folder and BAM .... Updated the default_form.php under my template folder and is functioning correctly now.

I did not realize the template folder held the files there also..... figured it was the files on the main root....

Comment: Joomla will always check for overrides first then fall back to the ones in the component folder.